# CSS: border only half works

Tags: css, html

I'm using CSS to create a border around a content holder but only the corner images are showing and not the repeating top sides or bottom.

```
.blog {
-moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 fi;
color: #000;
background-color: #FFF;
border-top-width: 30px;
border-right-width: 30px;
border-bottom-width: 30px;
border-left-width: 30px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
```

}

Any idea why it might not be working? I can't think of anything.
Thanks for reading!

edit:

here is the image I am using:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSnQL.png]

I am using standard div tags to add it to my html.

MANAGED TO FIX IT THANKYOU USING:

```
   border-style: solid;
border-width: 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
-o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
border-image: url(divborder.png) 27 stretch;
```

no idea what was wrong with the last one, cheers!

Comment: Just a tip: Also posting a demo created at jsfiddle.net can help a lot with question like these.

Comment: why do you dont use this short one: border: 30px solid #FFF;

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a property called `fi`. Perhaps you mean `fill`?

`border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 fill;`

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

```
border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 fill repeat;
```

Also just a suggestion, here's a condensed format since your border widths and styles are uniform.

```
.blog {
  -moz-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
  -o-border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 repeat;
  border-image: url(divborder.png) 30 27 27 fill repeat;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: no luck sorry, I'm using <div class="blog"> </div> to load it. is there any rules against putting div inside divs?

Comment: Odd, seems to work fine using your image as an example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FJDLB